# Filter array of object property name to new array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, es6-promise

Suppose I have an array of object, how to filter to a new array of object with only object property name. Should I use (Object.keys()), what is the best solution with es6.

```
data=[{
     deviceId:2
     deviceStatus:"Online"
     deviceType:"Tag"
     lastAliveMessage:null
     name: 'name:"Some Text'
     location: location.name
},{
     deviceId:2
     deviceStatus:"Online"
     deviceType:"Tag"
     lastAliveMessage:null
     name: 'name:"Some Text'
     location: location.name
}]
```

should be:

```
filteredArr = [{
  datakey: 'deviceID',
   label: 'label',
},
{
 datakey: 'deviceStatus',
 label: 'label',
},
{
 datakey: 'deviceType',
 label: 'label',
},
{
 datakey: 'deviceID',
 label: 'label',
},
{
 datakey: 'lastAliveMessage',
 label: 'label',
},
{
datakey: 'name',
label: 'label',
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried to code-golf it:

```
filteredArray = Object.keys(data[0]).map(key => ({datakey: key, label: 'label'}))
```